# Where does the CascadingParameter HttpContext come from in a Blazor server side app with identity?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-identity

Im currently learning blazor identity and am analyzing the built in identity files. Im not one to just use something without knowing more about what its doing so i was just curious if anyone could explain to me where the following line of code cascades from?

> [CascadingParameter] private HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; } =
> default!;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check the source codes of `AddRazorComponents` method

```
public static class RazorComponentsServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Registers services required for server-side rendering of Razor Components.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="services">The service collection.</param>
    /// <param name="configure">An <see cref="Action{RazorComponentOptions}"/> to configure the provided <see cref="RazorComponentsServiceOptions"/>.</param>
    /// <returns>An <see cref="IRazorComponentsBuilder"/> that can be used to further configure the Razor component services.</returns>
    [RequiresUnreferencedCode("Razor Components does not currently support trimming or native AOT.", Url = "https://aka.ms/aspnet/nativeaot")]
    public static IRazorComponentsBuilder AddRazorComponents(this IServiceCollection services, Action<RazorComponentsServiceOptions>? configure = null)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(services);

        // Dependencies
        services.AddLogging();
        services.AddAntiforgery();

        services.TryAddSingleton<RazorComponentsMarkerService>();

        // Endpoints
        services.TryAddSingleton<RazorComponentEndpointDataSourceFactory>();
        services.TryAddSingleton<RazorComponentEndpointFactory>();
        if (MetadataUpdater.IsSupported)
        {
            services.TryAddSingleton<HotReloadService>();
        }
        services.TryAddScoped<IRazorComponentEndpointInvoker, RazorComponentEndpointInvoker>();

        // Common services required for components server side rendering
        services.TryAddSingleton<ServerComponentSerializer>(services => new ServerComponentSerializer(services.GetRequiredService<IDataProtectionProvider>()));
        services.TryAddSingleton<WebAssemblyComponentSerializer>();
        services.TryAddScoped<EndpointHtmlRenderer>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IComponentPrerenderer>(services => services.GetRequiredService<EndpointHtmlRenderer>());
        services.TryAddScoped<NavigationManager, HttpNavigationManager>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IJSRuntime, UnsupportedJavaScriptRuntime>();
        services.TryAddScoped<INavigationInterception, UnsupportedNavigationInterception>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IScrollToLocationHash, UnsupportedScrollToLocationHash>();
        services.TryAddScoped<ComponentStatePersistenceManager>();
        services.TryAddScoped<PersistentComponentState>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<ComponentStatePersistenceManager>().State);
        services.TryAddScoped<IErrorBoundaryLogger, PrerenderingErrorBoundaryLogger>();
        services.TryAddEnumerable(
            ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IPostConfigureOptions<RazorComponentsServiceOptions>, DefaultRazorComponentsServiceOptionsConfiguration>());
        services.TryAddScoped<EndpointRoutingStateProvider>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IRoutingStateProvider>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<EndpointRoutingStateProvider>());
        services.AddSupplyValueFromQueryProvider();
        services.TryAddCascadingValue(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<EndpointHtmlRenderer>().HttpContext);

        // Form handling
        services.AddSupplyValueFromFormProvider();
        services.TryAddScoped<AntiforgeryStateProvider, EndpointAntiforgeryStateProvider>();
        services.TryAddScoped<HttpContextFormDataProvider>();
        services.TryAddScoped<IFormValueMapper, HttpContextFormValueMapper>();

        if (configure != null)
        {
            services.Configure(configure);
        }

        return new DefaultRazorComponentsBuilder(services);
    }

    private sealed class DefaultRazorComponentsBuilder(IServiceCollection services) : IRazorComponentsBuilder
    {
        public IServiceCollection Services { get; } = services;
    }
}
```

Here specify a  cascading value

```
services.TryAddCascadingValue(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<EndpointHtmlRenderer>().HttpContext);
```

Here's the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?view=aspnetcore-8.0) related with cascading parameter in .net 8

Comment: Thank you for this. Makes sense and had no idea you could cascade from the main program file.